# Marklogic REST API queries

Tags: rest, marklogic, marklogic-8

I have an XQuery that searches for XML documents that have a specific property value (metadata) associated with it. The query below works in the Q Console, however I need to execute it as a GET call using the REST API:

```
cts:search( fn:collection(), cts:properties-query(cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("type"),"executable")))
```

How do I convert this XQuery to a REST call that will return the same results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send a GET request to the /v1/search endpoint with a structuredQuery parameter set to the HTTP encoded a JSON or XML representation of a properties fragment query containing a value query on an element.  See:

- http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/search
- http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query#id_67222
- http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query#id_39758
- http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query

Answer (score 2):

This was resolved using the following query:

```
<query xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
<properties-fragment-query>
<value-query><element name="type" ns=""/>
    <text>executable</text>
</value-query></properties-fragment-query>
</query>
```

I HTTP encoded this query and appended it to the REST call like this:

http://*localhost:xxxx*/v1/search?structuredQuery=*encoded query*